# javascript increment by 1 simultaneously

Tags: javascript, increment

i hope that you can help me with this small problem of mine, i am currently trying to develop a incremental game for fun, and learning purposes, but i can not get my head around how to make it increase by 1 simultaneously,
like if i have 100 items / second. I want it to add 0-100 by 1 each second,

so instead off going like 
0
/* time lapse of second */
100

i want it go 
0-1-2-3-4-5-6 Etc, 
Curently this is my code.

```
    // the current amount of snus
this.snusAmount = 0.0;
//the current amount of snus per second
this.snuspSec = 0.0;
this.increaseBy = {knox: 0.1, offroad: 0.5, ld: 10, ettan: 19, goteborg: 57, general: 126, nick: 500, grov: 1337};
this.getSnus = getSnus;


function getSnus(){
var number = Math.abs(this.snusAmount);
var fixedNumb = number.toFixed(1);
return fixedNumb;
}

function addSnus(){
    this.snusAmount += this.snuspSec;
}

function getSnusPSec(){
    return parseFloat(this.snuspSec.toFixed(1));
}
```

If you require more information, i will try to add it as best as i can.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what problem are you having with that code? It's very hard to help when we don't know what all those methods do.

Comment: What is it currently doing?

Comment: (Best guess is that `this` doesn't refer to what you think it refers to but that's just a guess.)

Comment: @Juhana, like i said, it goes from 0 - 100 instantly each second and 100 - 200 i want it to count to 100 so you see the numbers, like cookie clicker has. if you know that game.

Comment: There's no way to know what could be wrong if we can't see code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Juhana i could send all 3 javascript files in pastebin if you like.

Comment: No thanks. Please trim out all irrelevant parts and paste them to the question.

Comment: @Juhana Edited the code in the post iteslf.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: i created a mini earning money game. it doesnt handle negatives yet (like you can buy and have negative money). it also doesnt handle decimals. but this should get you started on what you wanted for the purposes of the question and modified scope in the comments.

i only have 2 elements, but you can make an array, and loop through the array for addition income makers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalMoney = 0;
    var storeCount = 0;
    var hotelCount = 0;
    $('.addMoney').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        totalMoney = checkTotalMoney();
        totalMoney++;
        $('.money').html(totalMoney);
    });
    $('.addStore').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentTotal = checkTotalMoney();
        $('.money').html(currentTotal - 10); // subtract $10
        storeCount++;
    });
    $('.addHotel').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentTotal = checkTotalMoney();
        $('.money').html(currentTotal - 50); // subtract $10
        hotelCount++;
    });
    
    
    setInterval(function(){ 
        var currentTotal = checkTotalMoney();
        var totalStoreIncome = 0;
        var totalHotelIncome = 0;
        if (storeCount > 0) {
            totalStoreIncome = 1 * storeCount; // rate of 1/second
        }
        if (hotelCount > 0) {
            totalHotelIncome = 6 * hotelCount; // rate of 6/second
        }
        currentTotal = currentTotal + totalStoreIncome + totalHotelIncome;
        $('.money').html(currentTotal);
        
        if (currentTotal >= 50) //show different buying options
        {
            $('.hotel').show();
            $('.store').show();
        }
        else if (currentTotal >= 10) {
            $('.hotel').hide();
            $('.store').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.hotel').hide();
            $('.store').hide();
        }
        
        updateCounts(storeCount, totalStoreIncome, hotelCount, totalHotelIncome);
    }, 1000);
});

function checkTotalMoney() {
    return parseInt($('.money').html());
}
function updateCounts(storeCount, totalStoreIncome, hotelCount, totalHotelIncome) {
    $('.storeIncome .count').html(storeCount);
    $('.storeIncome .profitRate').html(totalStoreIncome);
    $('.hotelIncome .count').html(hotelCount);
    $('.hotelIncome .profitRate').html(totalHotelIncome);
    $('.totalProfit').html(parseInt(totalStoreIncome) + parseInt(totalHotelIncome));
}
```

```css
.income div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.items div {
    background-color:lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
You have: $<span class="money">0</span><br/><br/>
You are earning income from the following:
<div class="income">
    <div class="storeIncome">
        Stores owned: <span class="count">0</span><br/>
        Rate of profit of each store: $1/second<br/>
        Total Stores Profit: $<span class="profitRate">0</span> / second
    </div>
    <div class="hotelIncome">
        Hotels owned: <span class="count">0</span><br/>
        Rate of profit of each store: $6/second<br/>
        Total Hotels Profit: $<span class="profitRate">0</span> / second
    </div><br/><br/>
    Total Profit from Stores and Hotels: $<span class="totalProfit">0</span> / second<br/>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="addMoney">Earn $1</a>
<br/><br/>
<div class="items">
    <div class="store" style="display:none;">
        Buy a STORE for $10?<br/>
        Rate of income: $1/second<br/><br/>
        <a href="#" class="addStore">Buy STORE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hotel" style="display:none;">
        Buy a STORE for $50?<br/>
        Rate of income: $6/second<br/><br/>
        <a href="#" class="addHotel">Buy Hotel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, let try to explain better, the max number, will be infinite, and you start with 0 Snus and then you click till you have like 15 snus, and buy a store kinda, wich gives you 0.1 snus / second, automaticly, the snus / second will change all the time considering you are buying stuff that will give you different amounts of snus / second, so this option won't work but thank you anyways :)

Comment: @TheDonBase see edited code and demo to see if this is what you wanted

Comment: this is what i've had all along, if you have 4 stores, it adds instantly 4$ each second, but instead of it adding 0+4 i want it to add 0+1 till it gets to 4 under the 1 second. if you understand me.